# Proving that a torsion subgroup is normal

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, torsion-groups

We prove,  that the torsion group $T$, which has elements of finite order, $T\subset G$, is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Definition: A subgroup T, is normal if $gTg^{-1}= T \ \forall g\in G$.\

UPDATE 2: By discussion below, I simplify the original approach to the following.

For a case of finite order, we have:

\begin{equation}
    (aga^{-1})^{n}=(a^{-n}a^{n}g^{n}a^{n}a^{-n})=((a^{-1}ga))^n
\end{equation}

which applies for $g$:

\begin{equation}
    (gg^{-1})^n=(g^{-n}g^n)=(g^{-1}g)^n
\end{equation}

Update 3: Trying with some examples n=(2,3)

\begin{equation}
    (aga^{-1})^2=aga^{-1}aga^{-1}= agega^{-1}=ag^2a^{-1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    (aga^{-1})^3=(aga^{-1}aga^{-1})aga^{-1}= agega^{-1}e=ag^3a^{-1}
\end{equation}

Is this fine?
Thanks

Comment: The order of a conjugate is the same as the order of the original element.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by limit here. Conjugation preserves order, that's it. By the way, the subset of torsion elements is not always a subgroup. (but if it is a subgroup, it is indeed normal)

Comment: OK. Thanks. How can I add that the conjugation preserves the order, in terms of symbols to the elements (ab) ?

Comment: In a general group, the set of torsion elements do not necessarily form a subgroup. Are you assuming that they do?

Comment: @ViolaPlayer why are you focusing on elements $ab$? You just need to prove that if $g$ has finite order then so does $a^{-1}ga$.

Comment: @user1729 Ok, I have tried , see the update.

Comment: Your new attempt doesn't make sense. I mean, $gg^{-1}\neq g$ and $aga^{-1}\neq a^{-1}aga^{-1}a$. So...what does it mean (in symbols) for an element to have finite order?

Comment: In symbol it means that $g^n=e$

Comment: Great. So, if $g^n=e$, then what is $a^{-1}g^na$ equal to, and why?

Comment: Since we want to prove that a torsion group is normal, then it must follow as a criteria that $aGa^{-1}= G \ \forall a\in G$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132427/discussion-between-user1729-and-viola-player).